# MySQL query returns weird malformed results when querying too many rows

Tags: mysql, sql

[Table columns here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zmc8.png)

Table has about 1.4 million rows.

1 year query:

```
SELECT windDir, 
count(windDir)/(
    SELECT COUNT(windDir) 
    FROM archive 
    WHERE windDir is not NULL AND dateTime >= 1466719200) as frequency 
FROM weewx.archive 
WHERE windDir is not NULL AND dateTime >= 1466719200 
GROUP BY windDir 
ORDER BY windDir ASC;
```

Returns correct result (cba to copy frequency results)

```
+---------+-----------+
| windDir | frequency |
+---------+-----------+
|   0     |     x     |
|  22.5   |     x     |
|  45     |     x     |
|  67.5   |     x     |
|  90     |     x     |
| 112.5   |     x     |
| 135     |     x     |
| 157.5   |     x     |
| 180     |     x     |
| 202.5   |     x     |
| 225     |     x     |
| 247.5   |     x     |
| 270     |     x     |
| 292.5   |     x     |
| 315     |     x     |
| 337.5   |     x     |
+---------+-----------+
```

2 year query:

```
SELECT windDir, 
count(windDir)/(
    SELECT COUNT(windDir) 
    FROM archive 
    WHERE windDir IS NOT NULL AND dateTime >= 1435096800) as frequency 
FROM weewx.archive 
WHERE windDir IS NOT NULL AND dateTime >= 1435096800
GROUP BY windDir 
ORDER BY windDir ASC;
```

[RETURNS WEIRD WRONG RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDJ3X.png)

Only difference is dateTime, which changes how many rows is calculated over.

Could it be some kind of memory issue?

Even simplifying the query to something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT windDir
from weewx.archive
WHERE dateTime >= 1435096800 
ORDER BY windDir ASC;
```

return malformed query like the the one above.

Whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The column `winDir` is of type double, so those "weird malformed" results are just values of type double that are stored in your table. (Also note that they range from 0 to 360 so they are "degrees".) If you want more predictable results that are easier to read then adjust the precision of the `winDir` output, perhaps by using ROUND() such as this:

```
select
       w.windir 
     , w.numerator / f.denominator AS frequency
from (
      SELECT
            ROUND(windDir,1) AS windDir
          , COUNT(windDir)   AS numerator
      FROM weewx.archive
      WHERE windDir IS NOT NULL
      AND DATETIME >= 1435096800
      GROUP BY
            ROUND(windDir,1)
     ) AS w
CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT
            COUNT(windDir) * 1.0 AS denominator
      FROM archive
      WHERE windDir IS NOT NULL
      AND DATETIME >= 1435096800
      ) AS f
ORDER BY windDir ASC
;
```

Note I have pushed the calculation of the denominator into a cross join which I think will make it more efficient.